# Single value from a list of comma separated values when used in inner join in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, csv

Can anyone please help me with a query to return a single value from a list of comma separated values when used in inner join. I can paste the example query here.

```
select * 
from Test.dbo.Test1 
   INNER JOIN  @TestTable T ON T.Name = ????
```

The table given is Test.dbo.Test1 .I had inserted the values to a table variable @TestTable and doing an inner join. The table is:-

```
Id  Name
1   John,Mili,Anil,Abhi
2   John,Abhi
3   John
4   Mili,Anil,Abhi
5   Anil
6   John,Mili,Anil,Abhi
```

I need a query in '???' space where I can select a single value from comma separated values in 'name' field and compare with the other.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

m`dbo` and `@` are hints it's MS Sql Server. Use a splitter table valued function of choice, Jeff Moden's one http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ performs very good. So

```
select * 
from Test.dbo.Test1 a
   INNER JOIN  @TestTable T on T.Name in (select item from [DelimitedSplit8K](a.Name, ','))
```

But may I say the best way to solve the problem is to have no such a problem. Any chance `Test.dbo.Test1` could be refactored to have a separate row for every item from `Name` column? Then take this opportunity.

it's possible to use plain `like`, but note it prevents optimizer from using any index. In the above version at least index on T.Name can be used.

```
select * 
    from Test.dbo.Test1 a
       INNER JOIN  @TestTable T on ','+a.Name+',' like '%,'+T.name+',%'
```

Comment: Can we use CHARINDEX and solve the above.? I mean without using a function, just by using a simple select query.